# Load a htm from file location into an iframe inside a chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, file-access

I need to enable a google chrome extension to be able to access a folder on my machine to dynamically load an htm into an iframe.

There are too many files in my folder to list in the manifest one by one, plus this list may frequently change. So ideally I would like to have just the folder available to the extension.  That being said, even having the full path doesn't work, which I guess is because its on the file system and not a relative path to the extension.  Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

I'ved tried this as my manifest:

```
"web_accessible_resources": ["D:/myfolder/*.htm"]
```

and this:

```
"web_accessible_resources": ["file:///D:/myfolder/*.htm"]
```

I've also tried this as my manifest:

```
"web_accessible_resources": ["file:///D:/myfolder/specificfilename.htm"]
```

In my extension i'm trying to load using this syntax:

```
var fileUrl = chrome.extension.getURL("specificfilename.htm"); 
...
...
ifrm.setAttribute("src", fileUrl);
```

but I'm seeing these error messages:

```
GET chrome-extension://invalid/ net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
```

and

```
execution.js:68 Not allowed to load local resource: file:///D:/myfolder/specificfilename.htm
```

Complete manifest file:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Example extension",
  "description": "Example extension desc",
  "version": "1.1.5",

  "browser_action": {
  "default_title": "Example extension",
  "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },

  "permissions": [
    "<all_urls>",
    "activeTab",
    "tabs"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": [ "background.js" ],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "file:///D:/myfolder/*.htm",
    "file:///D:/myfolder/specificfilename.htm"
  ]
}
```

background.js:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, 
        {
        file: 'execution.js'
        }, 
        completed);
});

function completed() {
    alert("done");
}
```

execution.js

```
var reportIframe = prepareFrame();

function prepareFrame() {

    var fileUrl = chrome.extension.getURL("specificfilename.htm");

    var ifrm = document.createElement("iframe");
    ifrm.setAttribute("src", fileUrl);
    ifrm.style.width = "640px";
    ifrm.style.height = "480px";
    document.body.appendChild(ifrm);

    return ifrm;
}
```

Comment: `Resource` means something within your extension package.

Comment: You probably need to enable `[x] allow file access` on chrome://extensions page. You might need to change the CSP of the page that has the iframe.

Comment: I dont have the [x] available. Is it an manifest option?

Comment: Yes its been running in developer mode.

Comment: adding     "<all_urls>" to permissions does indeed enable the [x] allow access to file URLS. Thank you.  Will see what this does.

Comment: Edited @Makyen; hope fully that satisfies you to offer something contructive?  @wOxxOm the [x] allow access to file URLS hasn't helped.